# test class asserts for pagereference

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

I am new in SalesForce, Please Help me,

my **Apex** Class...

```
public  class sturecords {
    public String name { get; set; }
    public String address { get; set; }
    public String phone { get; set; }
    public Integer zipcode { get; set; }
    public String email { get; set; }


    public  PageReference insertNewRecord(){

        Student__c stu=new Student__c();
        stu.name=name;
        stu.address__c=address;
        stu.phone__c=phone;
        stu.zipcode__c=zipcode;
        stu.email__c=email;
        insert stu;

        PageReference PageRef = Page.StudentList;
            PageRef.setRedirect(true);
            return PageRef;
    }

    public PageReference cancel(){
        PageReference pageRef=Page.StudentList;
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        return pageRef;
    }
}
```

My **Test Class**

```
@isTest
public class sturecordTest {

    @isTest
    static void insertNewRecordTest(){

        sturecords stu = new sturecords();
        stu.name='abc';
        stu.address='chd';
        stu.phone='123456789';
        stu.zipcode=123456;
        stu.email='bb@gmail.com';
        stu.insertNewRecord();

        Decimal  zipCode = [SELECT zipcode__c FROM student__c ORDER BY zipcode__c DESC LIMIT 1 ].zipcode__c;

        System.assertEquals(stu.zipcode, zipCode);
    }

    @isTest
    Static void cancel(){

        sturecords stu = new sturecords();
        PageReference page=stu.cancel();
        PageReference expectedPage  = new PageReference('/apex/studentlist');
        System.assertEquals(expectedPage, Page);
    }
}
```

Test class Failed in **cancel portion**......

Failed Message....

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected:
>   System.PageReference[/apex/studentlist], Actual:
>   System.PageReference[/apex/studentlist]*

Answer (score 1):

I suggest instead of asserting pagereference, just the url in assert

this way `System.assertEquals(expectedPage.getUrl(), page.getUrl());`

complete code

```
@isTest
Static void cancel(){

    sturecords stu = new sturecords();
    PageReference page=stu.cancel();
    PageReference expectedPage  = new PageReference('/apex/studentlist');
    System.assertEquals(expectedPage.getUrl(), page.getUrl());
}
```

Comment: The issue may be that assertEquals may be comparing *by reference* instead of *by value*, which is fixed by Ratan's suggestion